# Why do I get an error when creating a table from an existing table in Oracle using a PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle

This is my code:

```
create or replace procedure p1
as
begin
create table emp_1 as (select * from emp);
end;

sql>exec p;
```

Then I get this error:

```
as ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: 
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P1' 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: why the procedure?  You would have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for DDL.  Just execute the sql statement directly, no procedure needed.

Comment: Why create `p1` then execute `p`? Why not execute `p1`?

Comment: iam executing p1 only

Answer (score 3):

You have several unclear issues :

1. Your procedure is p1 and you execute p. Why?
2. You can't execute create table statement inside a procedure like select or other DML. Use "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" statement for that.
3. Why you are trying to create the table inside the procedure ? You can execute the statement directly with no procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
    create or replace procedure p
    as
    begin

    execute immediate 'create table emp_1 as (select * from emp)'; 
    end;

    sql>exec p;
```

Comment: Thanks sending this .yes this procedure